# Is it possible to hide or remove system preference panes?

Tags: macos, system-settings

I have a number of System Preference panes I'd like to get rid of. My preference is to make them inactive so nothing loads, but not to delete them in case I ever want them back.

**What are my options? How do I do this?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer is **Yes** on both counts. That is, you can hide a preference pane or remove it altogether. See below for steps on doing each.

**Hiding System Preference panes**

To hide a System Preference pane:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences…
2. With your mouse, go to View > Customize…
3. This will reveal a checkbox at the bottom-right of each pane (see image below)

[image]

4. Untick the checkbox of any pane you want to hide
5. Click on the <kbd>Done</kbd> button at top-left of the window

**Note:** You can also use the above steps to reveal any previously hidden panes by ticking the checkbox at Step 4.

**Removing System Preference panes**

You can only remove 3rd party preference panes (i.e. ones which are not natively part of macOS). To do this:

1. Right-click on the preference pane in question
2. Select the *Remove “name“ Preference Pane* option (in the example image below the user is selecting to remove the Java preference pane)

[image]

**Login items**

In case you're just wanting to hide an item upon logging in, or want to stop it loading on startup, you can also hide or remove items from your login items. To do this:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences…
2. Click on Users & Groups
3. Make sure your user account is selected (it should be by default)
4. Click on the <kbd>Login Items</kbd> button
5. Now you will see a list of applications etc that automatically open when you log in
6. You can either:

   - Hide an item by ticking the checkbox on the left of it, or
   - Remove an item by selecting its name and then clicking on the minus - button below the list.

Comment: and when you hide something, you can still access it via the menu `View > ...`, for example.

Comment: you many also access hidden items through search...

Answer (score 8):

In System Preferences, choose View → Customize… and uncheck the items you wish to hide.

[image: System Preferences Customize]